# How can I access photos on my phone device using reactjs

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

I am creating a reactjs website and I need to upload photos from an iOS device (iphone, ipad). How can I access the iphone photos directory using a web browser?

When I click browse on the web, it opens a folder on the iphone and i am unable to access photos after that.

Is there a way around it?

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple>
```

this works well to access file directory on my desktop. but I wan to access the photos director on my iphone

[image]

Comment: In mobile are you trying to accessing the page in the safari browser or any other? can you also please tell what is the ios version you are using?

Comment: @PallamollaSai I am using chrome and safari on mobile. ios version 15

Comment: can you please share any screenshot. Is it showing any error? Is app permissions set properly?

Comment: can you try this once <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture/>

Comment: @PallamollaSai I have added an image with an edit text.